# Flyway's support for Groovy-migrations & conditional environment-specific data insertions

Tags: grails, groovy, flyway

We are working on a Grails-project, and exploring Flyway as a db-migration tool for us.

In our current architecture, we rely on Groovy-migration scripts (executed at application-startup) for conditional environment-specific data insertions (say 'some-data' in 'tableA' for Production against 'other-data' in the same table 'tableA' for pre-Production).

Q1. Does Flyway support Groovy-migration scripts?

Q2. If not, then how best can we achieve conditional environment-specific data insertions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Q1:** Java-based migrations are loaded as binary classes at runtime. Whether the source was Java or Groovy shouldn't matter here. **So yes, writing them in Groovy should work.**

**Q2:** Flyway supports **multiple locations** to load migrations from. These locations can then be **configured differently per environment** (in your case for PROD & PRE-PROD). You can use this to include different data based on the environment Flyway runs in.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! A little detailing of '_locations can then be configured differently per environment_' would be of great help. I see that we can provide '_Comma-separated list of locations on the classpath to scan recursively for migrations._' using **flyway.locations** property, but how to configure different locations per environment?

Comment: That's not part of Flyway itself. Simply configure it the same way you configure your other environment-specific settings.

Comment: I ran into a [Groovy 2.3.x issue](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-5351) with this. That seams to be fixed when Groovy 2.4 is out though.