# Spring -- skip flyway for this test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, flyway

Spring Boot web application with flyway.

So I switched from using H2 to MySQL and using Testcontainers to provide a DB for my backend tests when necessary.

Which means all my other integration tests (that **don't require a database** but **require loading the spring application context**) -- e.g. UI tests -- now fail because they don't have a DB to execute flyway migrations on.

```
[...]
[main] WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource - Registered driver with driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
[main] ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835)
    [...]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.DatabaseFactory.createDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:72)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1670)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1356)
    [...]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350
    [...]
```

How can I suspend flyway migrations for these tests?

Comment: answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27909642/using-flyway-to-load-data-conditionally-per-environment

Answer (score 4):

You should set `spring.flyway.enabled=false`. This can be done either using special profile in your tests or by using `TestPropertySource` annotation on your tests.