# Flyway: how to run script without adding it into migration?

Tags: java, spring, flyway

I have scripts for migration with `flyway`, they have corresponding naming & numeration, like:

```
V001__create_tables.sql
V002__init_tables.sql
...
```

& so on.

But I need to run test scripts for local development (in Embedded PostgreSQL), which should not come to migration.

I created script without migration, like `init_with_test_data.sql`, in extra package, & directed this package as additional in migration properties:

```
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration/common,classpath:db/migration/dev
```

But this script not run.

Please, give me advice, hot to run this script without dding it into flyway migration?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27909642/using-flyway-to-load-data-conditionally-per-environment